# MySQL is running slow on DB import

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

```
top - 18:52:07 up 17:16,  2 users,  load average: 3.68, 3.65, 3.62
Tasks: 381 total,   1 running, 380 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  :  0.3%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  0.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu11 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu12 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu13 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu14 :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.3%id, 96.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu15 :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32860264k total,  9521596k used, 23338668k free,   257740k buffers
Swap: 16498680k total,        0k used, 16498680k free,  8126252k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2274 mysql      1 -19  917m 233m 5804 S  1.6  0.7   9:01.93 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --u
  603 root      20   0     0    0    0 D  0.7  0.0   1:30.77 [jbd2/dm-0-8]
 6997 root       1 -19  194m 2796 1380 S  0.7  0.0   1:35.27 mysql -u USER -p DB
 1600 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:20.76 [kondemand/14]
13419 nobody    20   0 75124 5636 2100 S  0.3  0.0   0:01.59 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
26923 root      20   0 15296 1484  956 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.12 top -c
```

The DB import has been going for hours now and I've never seen one go so slow.

cat /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#skip-innodb
query_cache_limit=16M
query_cache_size=42M
query_cache_type=1
max_user_connections=70
max_connections=800
interactive_timeout=10
wait_timeout=10
connect_timeout=10
thread_cache_size=128
key_buffer=16M
join_buffer=1M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=1024
sort_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=2M
max_connect_errors=10
thread_concurrency=8
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
server-id=1

#[mysql.server]
#user=mysql
#basedir=/var/lib

[safe_mysqld]
err-log=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
open_files_limit=8192

#[mysqldump]
#quick
#max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=64M
sort_buffer=64M
read_buffer=16M
write_buffer=16M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

EDIT:

```
root@server [~]# iostat -c 3
Linux 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 (server.sf.co)         08/16/2013      _x86_64_        (16 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.54    0.00    0.22    2.12    0.00   97.12

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.08    0.00    0.10    5.88    0.00   93.93

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.08    0.00    0.13    5.96    0.00   93.83

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.04    0.00    0.08    5.97    0.00   93.91

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.10    0.00    0.17    6.11    0.00   93.62

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.06    0.00    0.04    5.97    0.00   93.93

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.04    0.00    0.06    5.94    0.00   93.95
```

FILE SIZE:

```
208M Aug 16 13:07 mysql.sql
```

DMESG:

```
udev: starting version 147
dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
dracut: rd_NO_DM: removing DM RAID activation
dracut: rd_NO_MD: removing MD RAID activation
dracut: rd_NO_MDIMSM: no MD RAID for imsm/isw raids
ahci 0000:00:11.0: version 3.0
ahci 0000:00:11.0: enabling device (0005 -> 0007)
  alloc irq_desc for 22 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
ahci 0000:00:11.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
ahci 0000:00:11.0: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 4 ports 3 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
ahci 0000:00:11.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo pmp pio slum part ccc
ahci 0000:00:11.0: setting latency timer to 64
scsi0 : ahci
scsi1 : ahci
scsi2 : ahci
scsi3 : ahci
ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xf0000000 port 0xf0000100 irq 22
ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xf0000000 port 0xf0000180 irq 22
ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xf0000000 port 0xf0000200 irq 22
ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0xf0000000 port 0xf0000280 irq 22
usb 5-3: new full speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
usb 5-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0557, idProduct=2221
usb 5-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 5-3: Product: Hermon USB hidmouse Device
usb 5-3: Manufacturer: Winbond Electronics Corp
usb 5-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
input: Winbond Electronics Corp Hermon USB hidmouse Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.0/input/input3
generic-usb 0003:0557:2221.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Winbond Electronics Corp Hermon USB hidmouse Device] on usb-0000:00:13.0-3/input0
input: Winbond Electronics Corp Hermon USB hidmouse Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.1/input/input4
generic-usb 0003:0557:2221.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Winbond Electronics Corp Hermon USB hidmouse Device] on usb-0000:00:13.0-3/input1
ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata1.00: ATA-8: WDC WD5002ABYS-02B1B0, 02.03B03, max UDMA/133
ata1.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD5002ABYS-0 02.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
pata_atiixp 0000:00:14.1: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
scsi4 : pata_atiixp
scsi5 : pata_atiixp
ata5: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0xc000 ctl 0xb000 bmdma 0x8000 irq 16
ata6: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0xa000 ctl 0x9000 bmdma 0x8008 irq 16
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
dracut: Scanning devices sda2  for LVM logical volumes vg_/lv_swap vg_/lv_root
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_/lv_home' [399.54 GiB] inherit
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_/lv_swap' [15.73 GiB] inherit
EXT4-fs (dm-0): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
EXT4-fs (dm-0): write access will be enabled during recovery
EXT4-fs (dm-0): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 412070
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 395434
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 413430
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 413423
EXT4-fs (dm-0): 4 orphan inodes deleted
EXT4-fs (dm-0): recovery complete
EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
dracut: Remounting /dev/mapper/vg_-lv_root with -o usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0,ro
EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/mapper/vg_-lv_root
dracut: Loading SELinux policy
SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 278017 rules.
SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 278017 rules.
SELinux:  9 users, 12 roles, 3900 types, 205 bools, 1 sens, 1024 cats
SELinux:  81 classes, 278017 rules
SELinux:  Completing initialization.
SELinux:  Setting up existing superblocks.
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-0, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev selinuxfs, type selinuxfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev hugetlbfs, type hugetlbfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devpts, type devpts), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev inotifyfs, type inotifyfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev anon_inodefs, type anon_inodefs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev pipefs, type pipefs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev debugfs, type debugfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sockfs, type sockfs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devtmpfs, type devtmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev bdev, type bdev), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev rootfs, type rootfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
type=1403 audit(1376631325.208:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
dracut:
dracut: Switching root
udev: starting version 147
shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
piix4_smbus 0000:00:14.0: SMBus Host Controller at 0xb00, revision 0
MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
EDAC MC: Ver: 2.1.0 Jul 16 2013
AMD64 EDAC driver v3.4.0
EDAC amd64: DRAM ECC disabled.
EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
 Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
 (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
EDAC amd64: DRAM ECC enabled.
EDAC amd64: F15h detected (node 1).
EDAC MC: DCT0 chip selects:
EDAC amd64: MC: 0:     0MB 1:     0MB
EDAC amd64: MC: 2:     0MB 3:     0MB
EDAC amd64: MC: 4:     0MB 5:     0MB
EDAC amd64: MC: 6:     0MB 7:     0MB
EDAC MC: DCT1 chip selects:
EDAC amd64: MC: 0:  8192MB 1:  8192MB
EDAC amd64: MC: 2:  8192MB 3:  8192MB
EDAC amd64: MC: 4:     0MB 5:     0MB
EDAC amd64: MC: 6:     0MB 7:     0MB
EDAC amd64: using x8 syndromes.
EDAC amd64: MCT channel count: 1
EDAC amd64: CS0: Registered DDR3 RAM
EDAC amd64: CS1: Registered DDR3 RAM
EDAC amd64: CS2: Registered DDR3 RAM
EDAC amd64: CS3: Registered DDR3 RAM
EDAC MC1: Giving out device to 'amd64_edac' 'F15h': DEV 0000:00:19.2
platform microcode: firmware: requesting amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam15h.bin
microcode: CPU0: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU0: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU2: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU4: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU6: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU8: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU10: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU12: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU12: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU13: patch_level=0x6000629
microcode: CPU14: patch_level=0x6000624
microcode: CPU14: updated (new patch_level=0x6000629)
microcode: CPU15: patch_level=0x6000629
Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.1.4-k
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2012 Intel Corporation.
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: Disabling ASPM L0s L1
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
  alloc irq_desc for 24 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: irq 24 for MSI/MSI-X
  alloc irq_desc for 25 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: irq 25 for MSI/MSI-X
  alloc irq_desc for 26 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: irq 26 for MSI/MSI-X
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:25:90:4c:e0:ac
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
e1000e 0000:01:00.0: eth0: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 0101FF-0FF
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Disabling ASPM L0s L1
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
  alloc irq_desc for 27 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: irq 27 for MSI/MSI-X
  alloc irq_desc for 28 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: irq 28 for MSI/MSI-X
  alloc irq_desc for 29 on node -1
  alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: irq 29 for MSI/MSI-X
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 00:25:90:4c:e0:ad
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
e1000e 0000:02:00.0: eth1: MAC: 3, PHY: 8, PBA No: 0101FF-0FF
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
SELinux: initialized (dev sda1, type ext4), uses xattr
EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-2, type ext4), uses xattr
Adding 16498680k swap on /dev/mapper/vg_-lv_swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16498680k
SELinux: initialized (dev binfmt_misc, type binfmt_misc), uses genfs_contexts
kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3-fs (loop0): using internal journal
ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 19
ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 18
ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 17
ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 16
ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 15
EXT3-fs (loop0): 5 orphan inodes deleted
EXT3-fs (loop0): recovery complete
EXT3-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
SELinux: initialized (dev loop0, type ext3), uses xattr
NET: Registered protocol family 10
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
powernow-k8: Found 1 AMD Opteron(TM) Processor 6272                  (16 cpu cores) (version 2.20.00)
powernow-k8: Core Performance Boosting: on.
powernow-k8:    0 : pstate 0 (2100 MHz)
powernow-k8:    1 : pstate 1 (1900 MHz)
powernow-k8:    2 : pstate 2 (1700 MHz)
powernow-k8:    3 : pstate 3 (1500 MHz)
powernow-k8:    4 : pstate 4 (1400 MHz)
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
conftest[6268]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000405068 sp 00007fff4d4b3380 error 4 in conftest[400000+a4000]
conftest[30368]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000405088 sp 00007fff052d82a0 error 4 in conftest[400000+a4000]
nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
```

smartctl -a /dev/sda

```
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital RE3 Serial ATA
Device Model:     WDC WD5002ABYS-02B1B0
Serial Number:    WD-WCASYD759683
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 259fb8cfc
Firmware Version: 02.03B03
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Fri Aug 16 19:30:33 2013 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                                        was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                ( 9480) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 112) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x303f) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   239   236   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1025
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       24559
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       17
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   112   109   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A) (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx1 port A)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3d)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
00:19.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:19.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:19.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:19.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:19.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:19.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
03:04.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736


 dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test oflag=direct bs=1024 count=102400
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 13.6567 s, 7.7 MB/s
```

Is there something wrong that is making this go so slow? I've done massive DB imports way bigger then this only to be done in minutes.

Comment: iowait shows the problem with disk. I see FS is ext4. What hardware are you running? Disk controller, interface, disks, array configuration etc... sysctl tuning, shmmax?

Comment: How would I get that information?

Comment: fdisk -l;uname -a; cat /etc/*-release;uptime;df -h;lspci;sysctl -a|grep shmmax;pvs;lvs;cat /proc/mdstat

Comment: server brand/model?

Comment: I already see that drives are direct-connected. And there is one 500 GB drive :S

Comment: How large is the file? How many tables are there?

Comment: Post all the info, then I write recommendations for you, including mysql configuration update.

Comment: Updating with more info now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers tell you all you need to know `Cpu14 :  0.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  3.3%id, 96.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st` that makes me think that you have slow disks.

Is this on a real server or a virtual server ?

Comment: This is a real server. Could the disk be bad?

Comment: Okay some questions : How big is what your trying to import ? What sort of disk(s) do you have ? can you give the output of `iostat -c 3`

Comment: Hey, Updated with new information.

Comment: Anything in the mysql log ? nothing in dmesg ?

Comment: Don't see anything that looks to be major.

Comment: run `smartcrl -a /dev/sda` to rule out anything obviously wrong with the disk.

Comment: Looks clean. Shows a PASSED.

Comment: 16 cpu's, 32gb RAM, 1 x 3 year old 500gb SATA disk. I would certainly have a look at replacing that disk. Is your import still running ?

Comment: Yes, it is still running ;/

Comment: Hrmm try this `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test oflag=direct bs=1024 count=102400` and lets see how fast that is :)

Comment: Ouch...  copied, 13.6567 s, 7.7 MB/s

Comment: Thanks. Should have known. This data center is KNOWN for bad hardware...

Comment: Actaully before you do that run dd with a bigger block size `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test oflag=direct bs=1M count=100` for reference on a 3 year old server I have it was 1.47867 s, 70.9 MB/s

Comment: Hardware is fine!!! This is _NOT_ bad HDD issue!